# VBA - Pull info from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not the greatest with VBA and haven't touched it in years therefore I resort to tutorials so I hope somebody can help!

In the long run I'm trying to, in the following order:

- Open an explorer window in one excel document via a button (Done!)
- select an excel doc (Hopefully selected multiple docs in the long run)
- pull info from a certain row/column of a sheet though to the original excel book

So far I've scoured/chopped and changed and found the following (Thanks JMax on this site)

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vFile As Variant

    'Set source workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Open the target workbook
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls", _
        1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
    'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open vFile
    'Set targetworkbook
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

    'For instance, copy data from a range in the first workbook to another range in the other workbook
    wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:D4").Value = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:B2").Value
End Sub
```

To me this looks in order however when It opens the excel doc it comes back with the 'subscript out of range' message.

What Im I missing? The cells and naming seem correct to me :(.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Use the macro recorder and look at the code it generates. You're welcome. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error is being thrown because a Worksheet name doesn't exist in on of the Worksheet Collections.

> wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
>
> Worksheets("Sheet3")

---

[image]